# Advanced Linear Algebra resources for a newbie

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, book-recommendation, point-cloud

At work I'm leveraging some linear algebra concepts that I don't feel confident with or plainly don't understand. I'm hoping to find a book which would help me with that.

I'm using stuffs like:

- projecting or intersecting lines on a plane
- fitting a plane to points with svd or ransac (not even sure what makes the most sense)
- calculating planarity of depthmap based on 3x3 structure tensor's eigenvalues (I see eigenvalues being used everywhere without understanding why they can be used in such way)

Can you think about a book or some online resource which would cover such topics in a fun and simple way? French/English are ok, I would love if it could includes python snippets but I'm afraid I'm asking too much

Thanks!

Comment: Your last two points are quite specialized. Before that it makes sense to improve your overall geometric and algebraic understanding of vectors and linear algebra. At an initial level I'd recommend either *Analytic Geometry with an Introduction to Vectors and Matrices* by Murdoch, or *Elementary Vector Geometry* by Schuster. At the next level, you'll find many recommendations here in English for linear algebra. In French, you might like *Algèbre linéaire* by Cairoli.